# Split string in SQL for mixed and particular comma separated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

How can I split string in SQL Server 2012 for such a table:

```
| ID  | Data     | 
+-----+----------+
| 1   |  abc,def |
| 2   |  def,abc |
| 3   |  def,ghi |
```

into this:

```
| ID  | Data1 | Data2| Data3 |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| 1   |  abc  | def  |  null |
| 2   |  abc  | def  |  null |
| 3   |  null | def  |  ghi  |
```

My aim is to get all abc's | def's | ghi's into columns of their own.

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Why `Data1` is `NULL` for last row alone ?

Comment: I want to know how to take a particular value e.g only 'def' from a string within a column and put it into a separate column, is that possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do?? For 1st two rows last column is zero.But for 3rd row first column is zero, why so??

Comment: @SharvilPopli -- yes, but the question here is why, for the first two rows, are the resulting split values going into `Data1` and `Data2` leaving `Data3` null but the third row has `Data1` null and the resulting split values go into `Data2` and `Data3`?  What is the logic for that?

Comment: @Sharvil Popli - Do you mean , you want to store all values which is abc should go to column Data1 , def to column Data2 and ghi to column Data3 ? And all these abc,def and ghi are some special distinct values ?

Comment: Lets say for Example, I have 2 rows with different IDs that have values _abc ,def_ and the second _def,ghi_. Is it possible to split this column into three columns showing that only show _abc_, _def_, _ghi_ sepaprately and the remaining as null. I know there are functions that can split strings into columns using commas as anchors for values like _abc,def_ for row one and _abc,def_ for row two but what if we have _abc,def_ and _def,abc_. How to get the **abc's** and **def's** into columns of their own?

Comment: @ANK yes, that is what I'm asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a #Temp table to store the parsed results.  Perhaps you can migrate into a cte

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Data varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'abc,def'),
(2,'def,abc'),
(3,'def,ghi')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
      ,ColName = 'Data'+cast(DENSE_RANK() over (Order By RetVal) as varchar(25))
Into #Temp
From @YourTable A
Cross Apply (
              Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                    ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
              From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(A.Data,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
              Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B


Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(ColName) From #Temp For XML Path('')),1,1,'')   
Select  @SQL = 'Select ID,' + @SQL + ' 
                From (Select ID,ColName,RetVal From #Temp) A
                Pivot (max(RetVal) For ColName in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
ID  Data1   Data2   Data3
1   abc     def     NULL
2   abc     def     NULL
3   NULL    def     ghi
```

Comment: Thanks John, you are a champ! Do you know of any good resources online where I can learn how to create such code?